# (-bash: initdb: command not found) When installing postgres mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, postgresql, psql

I get the following error (-bash: initdb: command not found) in the terminal when trying to install postgres on my mountain lion mac osx?

Also, does any one have a good resource for installing postgres, and setting it up?  Working with bash and setting the proper path.

I have been trying to install postgres all day and have no luck, I am working with Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 0):

The error probably means that your path is not set correctly; what you'll need to do in order to fix it depends on how you're trying to install it.

In any case, the absolute easiest way to get Postgres running on a Mac is Postgress.app (http://postgresapp.com).  Just download, drag to Applications, and start.

Comment: I downloaded/installed it, but when I click it opens to postgress.app site on the browser.  How do I access and setup a db and user?

Comment: Do you see the elephant icon in your menu bar? It has an item for the documentation, which is here: http://postgresapp.com/documentation